# Integer out of range in PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to save a number representing the length of a file (4825733517).  The column is set to type integer.  I don't have any validations or restrictions set.

```
RangeError: 4825733517 is out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 4
```

Should I be using some other column type for this value?  (on rails 4.2.4)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For columns of type `integer`, the `:limit` value is the maximum column length in bytes ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column)).

With 4 byte length, the largest signed integer you can store is 2,147,483,647, way smaller than your value of 4,825,733,517. You can increase the byte limit, for example to 8 bytes to be a long integer (a [bigint PostgreSQL type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html)), this will allow you to store signed values up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

You can do this with a migration create it with something like `rails generate migration change_integer_limit_in_your_table`, and the following code:

```
class ChangeIntegerLimitInYourTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :your_table, :your_column, :integer, limit: 8
  end 
end
```

Comment: FYI this is a great answer and *almost* worked for me. What **did** work was all the same syntax but `change_column` instead of `update_column`. I'm using Rails 4.2.6 so maybe "update_column" is deprecated.

Comment: You are absolutely right - `update_column` is simply incorrect, I might've got a wrong cue from the other answers when first writing this. Edited the post, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 5):

According to [the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html) an integer have a range from -2147483648 to +2147483647. So your number is to big for this type.

Update your column and use the parameter limit to indicate that you want to have a `bigint`.

```
change_column :table, :column, :integer, limit: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the length of the column in your database with a migration :

```
update_column :my_table, :my_column, :integer, limit: 12
```

It will allow you to store bigger integers.

Comment: 12 bytes is completely overkill, and also doesn't correspond to an available numeric type in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I just put 12 as an example. We don't even know the maximum integer he will need to save.