# Increase ActiveModel ID Range to 8 byte

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I've been [digging around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517403/integer-out-of-range-in-postgresql-database) to see how I could have all my newly and subsequent Model id's to have a limit of 8 byte. Answers show how to when adding a new table column; I want whenever I create a new `Model`, it would automatically has a `limit` of 8 byte. Possible?

When creating a new model, I get:

> ActiveModel::RangeError: 36565651767 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4

Where to change this limit from 4 to 8?

Answer (score 0):

A [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066340/how-to-use-long-id-in-rails-applications) but since there will be errors:

> you can't redefine the primary key column 'id'. To define a custom primary key, pass { id: false } to create_table.

Which means your table should look like this:

```
class MyModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :my_models, {id: false } do |t|
      t.column   :id, limit: 8
      ...
     end
  end
end
```