# Max number for ActiveModel::Type::Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, numbers, byte, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I'm trying to store the number `3980040429` as an ID for an object, but I'm etting the following error:

```
ActiveModel::RangeError (3980040429 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4 bytes)
```

Doesn't the 4 bytes equal to `4 294 967 296`?

```
4 bytes × 8 bits = 32 bits 
2³² = 4 294 967 296
```

As I'm appearantly wrong - what's the max integer I can save for an ID?

I'm on Rails 5.2 and Postgres 9.6.

Comment: Maybe it's a signed integer. `2**31`, plus or minus...

Comment: It seems that the accepted answer here answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/33517626/2199600

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a signed 4 byte integer.

So the maximum value it can have is 2³¹ - 1

2147483647